# How to find host uptime in vmware from ansible

Tags: command, ansible, vmware, uptime

How to find the machine uptime in vmware from ansible.

I want to find the host uptime without connecting to the machine.

using ansible

> ansible_vm_facts

I could able to get some details like

> os, machine_name

but I did not get the uptime.

I followed the following documnets but no luck. nothing worked for me.
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_vm_facts_module.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_host_module.html

Answer (score -1):

The primer from ansible documentation explains what info you can obtain with the debug module:

```
register: vmvariable

- debug:
      var: vmvariable
```

but I think that you cant get uptime value without getting facts from the host.

I think you can get this var from facts cache, but this fact will not be relevant.

Comment: @samuel liew - this would not work. if I use this I am not getting all the values